# Magento 2 How to check Product Customizable option set or not?

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I tried to check product customizable option is exists or not but it is not working.

I have a Product Id so just I had to check if this product customizable option is set or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Try This Code**

```
  protected $_productloader;  

  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader
    ) {

        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
    }
    public function getProductHasOption($id)
    {
        $prdData = $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
        return $prdData->getData('has_options');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have product object then simply use below code

```
if($product->hasOptions){
  echo "Yes, Product has Option.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Class Sample
 */
class Sample
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * Sample constructor.
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param $productId
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasCustomizableOption($productId)
    {
        try {
            /** @var Product $product */
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
            return $product->getHasOptions();
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $exception) {
            $this->logger->error($exception);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```